# Creating the row in the second table of two linked tables (linked via a fk) not working

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno, GWT, java and MySQL.

I am writing rows to two tables that are linked via a fk. The write to the first table works fine. I then return the key from this write (using Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) to the next write. When this write is performed I get an error "java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1". I have displayed the value being passed to each parameter and there are values.

The first column in both tables is the an auto increment pk. The second column in the second table is the fk.

The console is (the first five lines displayed are the values being passed to the parameters and the first is the fk):

```
cd_id = 6
section = Cubs
pack = Explorer
start date = 2013-06-28
end date = 2013-06-28
SQLException createYouthMember 1.
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2611)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2586)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2432)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection.createYouthMember(MySQLConnection.java:342)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:205)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

The Development Mode is:

```
13:16:16.910 [WARN] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method '@com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplIE9::getBoundingClientRectTop(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;)': Rounding double (216.00999450683594) to int for int
```

The relevant server side code is:

```
public YthMmbrSectDtls createYouthMember(String youthMemberId,
        String surname, String firstname, Date dob,
        String password, Date archived, String scout_no, String sectionDetailsId,
        String sectionCubDetailsId, String section, String pack, Date startDate, Date endDate) {

    YthMmbrSectDtls ythMmbrSectDtls = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
    Integer cd_id = 0;

    String queryCubDetailsTable = 
             "INSERT INTO at_cub_details "
             + "(cd_surname, cd_first_name, cd_dob, cd_archived, cd_scout_no) "
             + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    String querySectionDetailsTable = 
             "INSERT INTO at_section_details "
             + "(cd_id, sd_section, sd_pack, sd_start_date, sd_end_date) "
             + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryCubDetailsTable, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
      ps.setString(1, surname);
      ps.setString(2, firstname);
      ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) dob);
      ps.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) archived);
      ps.setString(5, scout_no);

      ps.executeUpdate();


      ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(querySectionDetailsTable);

      //Get foreign key from insert into at_cub_details
      ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
      if (rs.next()) {
          cd_id = rs.getInt(1);
      };

      System.out.println("cd_id = " + cd_id);
      System.out.println("section = " + section);
      System.out.println("pack = " + pack);
      System.out.println("start date = " + startDate);
      System.out.println("end date = " + endDate);
      ps.setInt(1, cd_id);
      ps.setString(2, section);
      ps.setString(3, pack);
      ps.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) startDate);
      ps.setDate(5, (java.sql.Date) endDate);

      ps2.executeUpdate();

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps2 != null) {
            try {
                ps2.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 4.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return ythMmbrSectDtls;
}
```

And the tables are:

[image: at_cub_details table]

[image: at_section_details table]

[image: foreign key setup]

I would appreciate any help. Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps` should be `ps2`

```java
ps2.setInt(1, cd_id);
ps2.setString(2, section);
ps2.setString(3, pack);
ps2.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) startDate);
ps2.setDate(5, (java.sql.Date) endDate);
```

Comment: Thanks peterm, my apologies for wasting everyone's time with such a silly mistake and my sincere thanks for your help. Regards, Glyn.